# Как проверить выполнился запрос к базе через PDO или нет?

Tags: php, pdo

Странный вопрос, но я найти не могу. Как в PDO проверить успешно ли выполнился запрос к бд ?
`$result = $this->db->query($q);` Возвращает Объект всегда.

```html
public function query($sql, $params = []) {
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
  if (!empty($params)) {
   foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $val);
   }
  }
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt;
 }
```

Comment: В доке сказано: _Возвращаемые значения 
PDO::query() возвращает объект PDOStatement или FALSE, если запрос выполнить не удалось_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В комментариях уже сказано, что в случае ошибки возвращается false, но как вариант можете посмотреть сколько строк затронул запрос:

```
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
     // запрос удался
} else {
     // запрос по каким-то причинам не выполнен 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не привык я еще к PDO

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($result && !is_string($result)) { //return true если успешно
  //код
 }
```

Comment: Он всегда true. Даже если нету поля в бд и тд. В $result приходит строка с запросом

Comment: @Andrii естественно, вы ведь возвращаете результат `prepare` (подготовки запроса), а не `execute` (выполнения). Хотя по-хорошему, в ответе это действительно не сказано.